# Why CLR optimizing away unused static field with initialization?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, initialization, static-members

Let's have two code snippets:

**A:**

```
public class Foo
{
    private static Bar _unused = new Bar();
}
```

**B:**

```
public class Foo
{
    private static Bar _unused;

    static Foo()
    {
        _unused = new Bar();
    }
}
```

In case **A** the CLR will not even call the Bar ctor (unless it is debug build or the debugger is attached), however in case **B** it is called under all circumstances.

The thing is that in Bar constructor one can have calls that will make this instance reachable from elsewhere - most typically *events subscriptions*.

So:

- *Why are the cases **A** and **B** evaluated differently?*
- *Why the CLR is not calling Bar ctor at all in case **A** - as it
  should not evaluate it as garbage until ctor is finished and instance
  is assigned to the appropriate field?*

Comment: is `Foo` ever used in `B`?

Comment: @HansPassant in snippet A, `Foo` is flagged with `beforefieldinit` in the IL. See [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx).

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski Thank you for a very great answer! It's actually even more correct than the one accepted (but sadly comments cannot be marked as answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [don't create a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, **the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class**.

If you [do have a static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically **before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.**